# How to move 1 column card to to another column bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to move card from one column to another column?

When the page is reached to mobile view then card 3 should move to 2nd column in middle of card 1 and card 2
How to achieve this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Demo content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class= "card">card 1</card>
      <div class="card">card 3</card>
      <div class="card">card 2</card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">card 3</card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which card 3?  You want to use css or bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Use the responsive display classes.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Demo content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">card 1</div>
      <div class="card d-md-none">card 3</div>
      <div class="card">card 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card d-none d-md-block">card 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/display/